# Saving an uploaded file (InputStream) to SQL Server through a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an ASP MVC application that uses HttpPostedFileBase to pick up uploaded files from a Razor view. These are collected into a List within a model which is then passed to the entity framework (v4.0.30319) in which I am calling a stored procedure to save the file to the database.

(I'm sure there are better ways of doing this but I am dealing with existing systems.)

In the model I have:

```
public List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
```

where the attachment object looks like:

```
public class Attachment
{
    public System.IO.Stream InputStream { get; set; }
    public String FileName { get; set; }
    public String ContentType { get; set; }
    public Int32 ContentLength { get; set; }
}
```

when I save the attachments I loop through the list and try to call the stored proc to save the input stream:

```
foreach(var file in ticket.Attachments)
    {
    if (file != null)
        {
        try
            {
            //create a byte array from the input file stream
            byte[] myData = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(myData, 0, file.ContentLength);

            ...

            var uploadResult = Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC mySP @file = {0}...", myData);
```

The problem appears to be that the stored proc is expecting a piece of text

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mySP] 
    @file           AS TEXT,
    @tcFileExtension    VARCHAR(50),
    ...
```

which is causing the error:

```
Operand type clash: varbinary is incompatible with text
```

what's the best way to convert the byte array (or InputStream) so that I can save it through the stored proc?

The uploaded file can be anything: xls, xlsx, pdf, tiff, doc etc

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the data is text, you can use a [Encoding.GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx) very simply to read all text into a string, and pass that with your stored procedure.

`var uploadResult = Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC mySP @file = {0}...", Encoding.GetString(myData);`

Comment: cheers. the file type can be anything. I've edited the question to reflect this

Comment: If the file type can be anything, your column is of the wrong type.

Comment: I think it's a blob instead of actual text

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your case the procedure @file parameter type should be `image`, not text.